# is Restore purchase button needed for iOS non renewal in app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Is a Restore Purchases button needed for non-renewable subscriptions if user's purchase status is stored and retrieved from a server?

In my iOS app, the user can Login to their account for using paid content.Is a Restore Purchases button needed where the In App Purchase details are stored on a server and users can log in to their account for using paid content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A restore purchases button is needed only if the app offers non-consumable IAPs, e.g. unlocking content.